# Change the values in the DF column pandas, Pythonic

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want change all strings in the pandas DF to the corresponding* integers.
I can use this routine:

```
k=0
for item in df['someColumn'].unique():
    df.replace(item, k)
    k += 1
```

or even I can do list comprehension... Anyway I want to ask, does somebody know about probably some specific method in Pandas, which could replace *ALL* strings in some column with the *corresponding* (=different) integer (or float) values..? **Please, propose only pythonic way.**

Probably some additional aspect. My column doesn't have some numeric values in the string format, just *really* strings (= concatenation of the chars):

```
C
asd
bbd
ksl
asd
asd
ksl
```

I want

```
C 
1
2
3
1
1
3
```

*Probably the word *corresponding* is a little bit confusing here, I'm very sorry

Comment: The correct method is to use [`convert_objects`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html#pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects) so `df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)`

Comment: something like `df['column'].astype(np.float)`?

Comment: you want to assign ints uniquely to the strings yes, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25963431/convert-pandas-series-from-string-to-unique-int-ids

Comment: Sorry got the wrong end of the stick, Jeff has correctly pointed you to the canonical answer

Comment: @Jeff, yes - exactly what I want. EdChum, thank you anyway :-)

Comment: You should probably vote to close and add a link to that question as duplicate, question won't be deleted so other users will be able to find the questions linking to same answer

Comment: ok, I'm agree, how I can vote here? I voted only for Jeff's answer

Comment: Can you see the 'close' button underneath your question? They'll be under the tags. If not you may not have enough rep to do so, if not don't worry and just move on.