# Pandas String Series to int normalisation for Tensor

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, normalization

I have a `Pandas::Series` object with repeated String values that I need to *normalise* into `int` values to feed into a TensorFlow.

I have looked at converting this into a `Category` as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25963431/convert-pandas-series-from-string-to-unique-int-ids) but it creates a code per item rather than identifying duplicates.

e.g. I wish for the following conversion

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'a', 'c'] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a bit change [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html):

```
print ((pd.factorize(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'a', 'c'])[0] + 1).tolist())
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need add `cat.codes` after convert to category

```
pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'a', 'c']).astype('category').cat.codes+1
Out[1407]: 
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    1
5    1
6    3
dtype: int8
```