# Change of categorical data to numeric data in the required columns so that a linear regression can be apply to it

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, linear-regression, one-hot-encoding

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2Z2b.png)

some of the columns on the given dataset contains categorical data. I have to change the data to the numeric so that I can apply simple linear regression to predict the score. The columns name are city, batting_team,    bowling_team, batsman, non_striker, bowler. I have to use the features to predict the score by applying simple linear regression.
I used one hot encoder to change the datatype but i'm not able to write perfect code for it. Please help me

Comment: I assume based on tags that you are trying to do this using python/pandas, possibly reading a csv or json? Can  you show what you have tried previously?

Comment: i tried to use onehotencoder but i am not able to code it properly

Comment: You could just convert the columns to categorical data using `astype('category')`, I think.
E.g. `df['city_codes'] = df['city'].astype('category').cat.codes`. This would create a column of `integer` type instead of string. See more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31464843/2029097

Comment: @gauravnajpande i mean, how are you pulling your data? For instance, if you are using a .csv or row based dataset, simply using the astype function allows you to set your data type

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To convert a string column to a numeric column for regression using scikit-learn (sklearn), you typically need to perform encoding on categorical data.

**OneHotEncoder** to convert the categorical string column into multiple binary columns, it's more suitable for not many unique values of category column.

**LabelEncoder** assigns a unique integer to each unique category in your string column.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, LabelEncoder
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
data["bowling_team"] = label_encoder.fit_transform(data["bowling_team"])

# or you can use another type of encoders
encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, drop='first')
data["bowling_team"] = encoder.fit_transform(data[["bowling_team"]])
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be more precise and beneficial to help you with that problem, if you have given the codes, dataset and output. However, here some steps you can do:

1. check the categorical data whether it can be changed to numeric one
2. If yes, you can cast categorical data into numeric one just like:

```
df['price'] = df['price'].astype("int")
```

This will return numeric data.
Hope you find it useful.